# Changing sign from $=$ to $\le$ in optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, soft-question

I am quite new to the field of convex optimization and I see that sometime people change the $=$ sign in the constraint into $\le$ sign in some research paper.

For example, the constraint $x + y = 1$ sometime become $x + y \le 1$.

They then make the claim that the problem corresponding to the constraint $x + y = 1$ has the same optimal solution as the problem with the constraint $x + y \le 1$.

So my question are:

1/ Why do this in convex optimization ? I guess that do this might make the Interior Point method operate easier but cannot make up my mind about it.

2/ Are there any requirement for this to work in convex optimization ? For example, the objective function is monotonically increasing or decreasing or have some interesting property ?

3/ Does this approach still work for discrete optimization ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1/ Why do this ? I guess that do this might make the Interior Point method operate easier but cannot make up my mind about it.

In linear programming (LP), in a bounded polytope the solution can be obtained on one of the vertices. Thus, in you example, if we have a maximization problem $c_xx+c_yy$ with $c_x>c_y>0$, with the constraints $x + y = 1, y\geq 0, x\geq 0$ replacing $x + y = 1$ with $x + y \leq 1$ will not add new solutions. Here the solution is $(1,0)$ and the value of the optimization function is $c_x$.

> 2/ Are there any requirement for this to work ? For example, the objective function is monotonically increasing or decreasing or have some interesting property ?

Yes. The relaxation should not add new solutions. Once again, consider  the constraints $x + y = 1, y\geq 0, x\geq 0$, but now we minimize over $c_xx+c_yy$ with $c_x>c_y>0$. The solution for the minimisation function is $(0,1)$ with the value $c_y$. If we relax $x + y = 1$ with $x + y \leq 1$, we will get the solution $(0,0)$, with the value $0$. But, if we relax $x + y = 1$ with $x + y \geq 1$, the original solution will remain the same. So, yes, the normal of the linear optimisation function is important.

> 3/ Does this approach still work for discrete optimization ?

Not necessarily in Integer Linear Programming (ILP). Relaxing the constraints may add additional integer solutions, and checking this in the general case is an NP-complete problem, if I'm not mistaken.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you but is it still true for convex optimization. My concern is really with convex optimization. Let me edit my question for clarity

Answer (score 3):

It's certainly not true in general that a convex optimization problem will have the same optimal solutions if a constraint is changed from $=$ to $\le$.   Counterexamples are very easy to construct.

What is true is that if the problem with $\le$ has an optimal solution that happens to satisfy the $=$ constraint, then this is an optimal solution of the problem with $=$.